# Python Pandas - Count consecutive grouped rows that satisfy condition and reset counter when false

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to add a new column labelled "counter" to the existing dataframe that will be calculated as shows in the example below:

| symbol | percentage | ??? counter ??? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | -1 |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| A | 5 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| A | 9 | -1 |
| A | 4 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 3 |
| B | 8 | -1 |
| B | 7 | -1 |

So the data is grouped per "symbol" and the logic for calculating the "counter" is like this:

- if the "percentage" is greater than 5, then "counter" is equal to -1
- if the "percentage" is less than 5, then we start counter with 0, if the next row for the same symbol is again less than 5, we increase the counter
- if the next row "percentage" is again greater than 5, we break the counting and set the "counter" column again to -1

I've tried something like this, but it's not good, since the reset is not working:

`df['counter'] = np.where(df['percentage'] > 5, -1, df.groupby('symbol').cumcount())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a mask and a custom `groupby`:

```
m = df['percentage'].gt(5)
group = m.groupby(df['symbol']).apply(lambda s: s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())

df['count'] = (df
               .groupby(['symbol', group])
               .cumcount()
               .mask(m, -1)
               )
```

Output:

```
   symbol  percentage  counter
0       A          11       -1
1       A           2        0
2       A           5        1
3       B           2        0
4       B           1        1
5       B           3        2
6       A           2        2
7       A           9       -1
8       A           4        0
9       B           2        3
10      B           8       -1
11      B           7       -1
```